# Why are my traps not growing?

Tags: strength, workout-routines, growth

Workout plan: http://teenbodybuilding.com/hagy3.htm

So I've been following the guide set forth at the url above. I've noticed very minor gains in size and I actually think the growth is just swelling caused by my creatine.

I'm following the guide and I'm also waiting 2 minutes before starting a new set (this was set forth in a chart posted here a while back)

I'm shrugging up to 315 lbs. I'm using straps to help hold the weight.

So what can I do to make my traps grow?

Note: I just realized that the link is for teen body building. Not sure if that makes a diff.

```
The Workout:

For Delts:

 - Warm up with 1 set of light dumbbell presses
 - 3 sets of dumbbell shoulder presses at 8-6-6(do military press about every other week).
 - 3 sets of forward lateral raises at 8-6-6
 - 3 sets of side lateral raises at 8-6-6
 - 3 sets of rear laterals at 8-6-6

For Traps:

 - Warm up with a light pair of dumbbells (not too light)
 - 4 sets of forward shrugs at 10-8-8
 - 4 sets of reverse shrugs at 12-10-8 (will have to go lighter on theses till you get the hang of it).
 - Burnout with as many reps as you can do with half the weight you did at 8 reps for the reverse shrugs.
```

Comment: I can't get to the link, could you summarize it in your post?

Comment: Could you detail your diet? Are you recovering well--plenty of sleep, a couple rest days every week?

Comment: DAve, diet is normal, I eat healthy, take protein and vitamins. Probably 3000-4000 calories a day. I rest 4-5 days before doing traps and shoulders again

Comment: How many complete rest days, without working other muscle groups?

Comment: ...what are your ultimate goals?  Cause from seeing that, you're not going to get too far in most things, at least that's what everyone tells me.

Comment: @DForck42 If [he can do 400lb squats and 200lb pistols](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/8223/squats-vs-stairs-whats-the-difference) I'd say that concerns about him not getting anywhere are misguided.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann I didn't know he was doing 400lb squats or pistols, he didn't include that as a part of this workout.  But i'm also ignorant so :-D

Comment: @DForck42 I'm lost, what do you mean? From seeing what? What do my squats have to do with anything?

Comment: @DaveLiepmann Normally 2-3 days with no workout (or only cardio)

Comment: they aint growin cuz u aint lifting heavy enough! hit it hard with clean shrugs, snatches, cleans, squats, etc, full body movements that will get you bigger and stronger overall.

Comment: @Andreas how heavy is "heavy enough"? I'm maxing at 315 and I started the program at 280 so I don't understand how it isn't heavy enough for me.

Comment: @DustinDavis for example in a set of 6x4, base your set weights on your 4 rep max for that day.  the last set should be at your 4 rep max

Comment: @Andreas ok I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen a pretty big improvement in my trap development since starting strong lifts. Breakdown of the program's lifts:

- squats:  don't activate your traps much from my knowledge
- bench press:  activates your traps isometrically to protect your neck while lifting
- Bo/pendlay rows: activates your traps
- overhead press: if you do these with the correct lockout/shurg at the top you get MAJOR workout of the traps
- deadlift: activates the traps

My suggestion would be to incorporate major lifts that require trap use in the lift instead of focusing on isolation exercises.  But with anything YMMV, and I don't know what else you're doing.

Comment: Ah, well I am bench pressing and doing overhead presses but I was doing those for my chest and they aren't much weight, was doing them more for tone. I haven't done pedlay rows in a while but I am doing a variation of them with a dumbell one arm at a time (Kneeling One Arm Row)

Comment: @dustindavis did a little research on the movements you listed in your training.  it **seems** that they all activate the traps in some fashion, so the only thing i can think of is that maybe you're not stressing them enough?  From some of the stuff i've read isolation movements (movements that focus on one sole muscle) are only effective to a point before you plateau and are no longer able to continue stressing that muscle without causing serious injury.  If you discover that may be the possibility i would definately consider compund lifts.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe I'm not going heavy enough, but I'm pretty much at max right now. I was thinking that maybe I'm not burning out with enough weight though. My traps are good sized when I flex, but I'm looking for them to pop when I'm not flexing. Maybe I need a diff routine. I'll look into strong lifts like you listed.